# nav doesnt work properly inside accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, nav

As you can see in the  picture. The nav doesn't response on the screen size when I place inside the accordion.

I try to resized it using jQuery when the accordion collapse but it doesn't work also.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

IMAGE [**LINK**](https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/s480x480/1530320_853820984712055_6924283041753346665_n.jpg?oh=cded507009e2d0f3219d6dc87f4a7412&oe=55E64070)

Comment: not able to see image.

Comment: UPDATED LINK http://i61.tinypic.com/10hvlv4.png

Comment: still can't see the image